# Group by and sum query on datatable

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a strongly typed `DataTable` that looks as follows:

```
|Team|FirstName|LastName|Hours
|A|Henry|Manny|3
|A|Henry|Manny|5
|A|Johny|Tenny|2
|A|Johny|Tenny|3
|B|Frank|Tank|4
|B|Frank|Tank|5
```

What I am trying to achieve is to sum the Hours by First and Lastname so my result table should look like:

```
|Team|FirstName|LastName|Hours
|A|Henry|Manny|8
|A|Johny|Tenny|5
|B|Frank|Tank|9
```

I tried so many thinks. One of it was:

```
dim query = From row In _dataset.Table1.AsEnumerable
Group by row.FirstName, row.LastName Into MAGroup = Group
Select New with { . First = row.FirstName, .Last = row.LastName, .Sum = sum(MAGroup.Hours)}
```

But always as soon as I start with the first anonymous member in the Select statement I don't get intellisense help and everything is underlined. I really would be so thankful if anyone could help me with the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to group by `FirstName`+`LastName`? Then group by an anonymous type:

```
Dim query = From row In _dataset.Table1.AsEnumerable()
   Group row By Name = New With {
        Key .FirstName = row.FirstName,
        Key .LastName = row.LastName
   } Into NameGroup = Group
   Select New With {
       .First = Name.FirstName,
       .Last = Name.LastName,
       .Sum = NameGroup.Sum(Function(r) r.Hours)
   }
```